# How to make my JQuery Masonry images float to top of page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

As you can see, at the top of my page, I have a user's avatar (profile picture) pulled to the left. I also have a column of all of that particular user's posts in another column to the right. The problem is that the posts don't start at the top of the page since the addition of the avatar.

[image: visual depiction]

Here is my view file:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3" 'pull-left'>

      <strong><%= @user.username %></strong> <br>
      <%= image_tag @user.avatar(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="things" class="transitions-enabled">

  <% @user.things.each do |thing| %>
    <div class='panel panel default'>
    <div class="box">
      <%= link_to image_tag(thing.image.url(:medium)), thing %>
      <div class='panel-body'>
      <strong><p><%= thing.title %></p></strong>
      <p><%= thing.description %></p>
  By <%= link_to thing.user.username, thing.user %>

  <% if thing.user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to edit_thing_path(thing) do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to thing_path(thing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
  <% end %>
</div> 
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**EDITS**

**Update**

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 avatar">

      <strong><%= @user.username %></strong> <br>
      <%= image_tag @user.avatar(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-9">
      <div id="things" class="transitions-enabled">

  <% @user.things.each do |thing| %>
    <div class='panel panel default'>
    <div class="box">
      <%= link_to image_tag(thing.image.url(:medium)), thing %>
      <div class='panel-body'>
      <strong><p><%= thing.title %></p></strong>
      <p><%= thing.description %></p>
  By <%= link_to thing.user.username, thing.user %>

      <% if thing.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_thing_path(thing) do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to thing_path(thing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
       <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div> 
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "things" and "avatar" under same `row` in Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 avatar"></div>
  <!-- Reduce it to 9 cols here -->
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div id="things"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't think you need pull-left, which also has a syntax error in your code - should be within same quotes with other classes

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't seem to work. I will update the original post with what I changed. The page still looks the same.